# How to design color boxes in android as shown in the image?

Tags: android, xml

How can we display  the colors as shown in the image where we can select more than one color ? The colored boxes must be checkboxes according to me but I am not able customize them

[image]

Comment: `The colored boxes must be checkboxes according to me` They could well be ImageViews or TextViews, according to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an xml resource in the drawable folder and use it in an `imageView` for instance for your question above it may look like this. Where by you use a shape called rectangle, giving it a solid colour as below and then also making the corner radius circular with 8dp. Then to display it you use an `imageView` and set it as a `src`. I have also added a  stroke. Remove it if you dont need it!

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle" >

      <solid android:color="#DFDFE0" />

      <size 
          android:height="8dp" 
          android:width="16dp" />

     <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

    <stroke
       android:width="3dp"
       android:color="#2E3135" />

  <gradient
      android:type="linear"
      android:angle="0"
      android:startColor="#f6ee19"
      android:endColor="#115ede" />

 </shape>
```

Comment: add "gradient" too.

Comment: I have edited the answer. And I have added gradient. If you don't like the stroke remove it. Also change the colours to something you like. You can also use it a background to your Views!

Comment: How to make the rectangle  horizontal ?

Comment: Ooooh @NihalReddy to make the rectangle horizontal it means you have to add the size of the box. After that you have to put width bigger may be 16dp than the height may be 6dp and it will be more horizontal. Check the answer again. Let me edit it for you!

Comment: Hey @NihalReddy I have put size where by height is 8dp and width is 16dp. Hence horizontal rectangle. Fill free to comment or mention me If it becomes hard to understand!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">

 <corners
    android:radius="5dp"/>

<gradient 
    android:startColor="#2E3135"
    android:centerColor="#000000"
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:angle="180"/>


  </shape>
```

Change the colour as your need.